# GreenFunction one dimensional heat equation doesn't evaluate

Tags: differential-equations

In the documentation `GreenFunction` I found the example with Neumann conditions at x==0 and x==1 `NeumannValue[0, True]`:

```
GreenFunction[{Derivative[0 , 1][u][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0 ][u][x, t]
, NeumannValue[0, True]}
, u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, t, {y, s}]
(*2 HeavisideTheta[-s + t] Inactive[Sum][E^(-\[Pi]^2 (-s + t) K[1]^2)Cos[\[Pi] x K[1]] Cos[\[Pi] y K[1]], {K[1], 1, \[Infinity]}]*)
```

which works as expected .

But if I set the boundary conditions separatly `NeumannValue[0, x==0], NeumannValue[0, x==1]` , which should give the same result, Mathematica v12

```
GreenFunction[{Derivative[0 , 1][u][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0 ][u][x, t]
, NeumannValue[0, x==0], NeumannValue[0, x==1]}
, u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, t, {y, s}]
```

doesn't evaluate and returns `GreenFunction[..]` the input!

What's wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: It means `GreenFunction[]` doesn't know what to do in the second case, and doesn't know it is equivalent to the first case. Please consider telling Support about this.

Comment: @ J. M. Thanks for your comment, it's curious and I'll contact support( Wolfram internetpage or is there a more direct way?)

Comment: [The usual page](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback), yes.

Comment: The outpu of the former code includes, in particular, `True + ((-I)^(
    1 + (-(1/4) - (5 I)/(12 Sqrt[3])) Floor[Arg[I - 6 I y]/(2 \[Pi])])
     I^((-(1/2) - 1/36 I (9 I + 5 Sqrt[3])) (1 + 
       Floor[Arg[I - 6 I y]/(2 \[Pi])])) 2^(
    4 + (-(1/4) - (5 I)/(12 Sqrt[3])).... `. In view of it I think the PDE problem under consideration has no Green function.

Comment: Both outputs are not true. I reported that in [CASE:4543698].

Comment: @user64494 Thanks for your comments. How did you check the outputs?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: If you look in above comment of me, you will see `True+something` which is meaningless.

Comment: Today, making use of a fresh kernel, I obtain the same results as in the question.

Comment: @user64494 Though this is the output of the first codeline `GreenFunction[]` in  my question? Which Mathematica version? ( mine: v12)

Comment: @user64494, "today, making use of a fresh kernel, I obtain the same results as in the question." - then please let me remind at this juncture that if you'll be doing checks like these, make sure you do it on a fresh kernel before commenting, lest you confuse other people.